# pyperclip paste() function adding letter "u" to every paste

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyperclip

```
>>>import pyperclip  
>>>pyperclip.paste()  
' '  
>>>pyperclip.copy('Hello World!')  
>>>pyperclip.paste()  
u'Hello World!'  

 
>>>pyperclip.copy('text')  
>>>pyperclip.paste()  
u'text'
```

Every time I use the paste function it prints a u before my string.  When I opened the idle I started with the paste function and it pasted empty `''`, but as soon as I add any text to the string, the paste function prints a `u'And then my sting here'`.

Comment: That's just telling you that the string is a Unicode string (and furthermore, that you're using an obsolete Python 2.x version, as Unicode strings became the default in 3.x).  The `u` isn't actually part of the string.